# Checking a single bit using the bitwise and (ampersand) operator

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am trying to understand this bit of code, the method addBittoTree needs a boolean to be passed through. I am not quite sure as to what it is checking. I do not understand why there is an ampersand for currentByte and -128, is it using that as an addition operator?

```
byte currentByte = dis.readByte();
tree.addBitToTree( (currentByte & -128) == -128 );
```

Comment: From whnece is this code? Looks like a clumsy way to check whether `currentByte < 0`

Comment: Agreed, I never seen anybody use negative numbers for bit masking.

Comment: @Ingo i bet the programmer is a C programmer converted to Java thinking his bithackery will make the Java program fast! :|

Comment: @Ingo, it is from my friend. What you said makes much more sense to me and that was my original thought, but I just did not understand his reasoning behind it and how the ampersand can check if its minus or not

Comment: @Aniket - Yes. Or maybe someone who himself does not fully understand 2s complement notation, and after 10 stupid questions on SO came up with that.

Comment: @Dmitry there is a HUGE amount of code using negative numbers for bitmasking! Look in any C API.

Comment: I know, I am still a student of computer science, I haven't seen much of that... In fact everyone except me is terrified of bit masking altogether...

Comment: @OliBlack Please tell your friend that he gains nothing by replacing 1 operation (<) by 2 (==, &), except that it makes his code unreadable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-128 in two's complemenet is

`1000 0000`

let's say your currentByte has the first bit set:

```
    1000 0000 // -128
        &     // bitwise logical and
    1010 1010 // currentByte (example)
is
    1000 0000 // -128
```

That is compared (`==`) to `-128`,  so you are passing the `boolean` parameter `true`.

Another example where the first bit is not set:

```
    1000 0000 // -128
        &     // bitwise logical and
    0011 1110 // currentByte (example)
is
    0000 0000 // 0
```

That is compared (`==`) to `-128`,  so you are passing the `boolean` parameter `false`.

Since this way of doing it always passes `true` to the method, when the first bit is set, and `false`, when it is not set, and we know that all positive numbers don't have the first bit set and all the negative ones do, it is equivalent to simply write:

```
tree.addBitToTree(currentByte < 0);
```

Comment: You should explain that `&` is logical `and`, I don't think the questioner understands that.

Comment: I think ive got it now, thanks alot, was exactly what I needed to know :)

Comment: http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/108/b/f/thanks_alot_by_kiki_akuma-d3eafmb.png